# How to place Navigation bar and its background image over a background color of the page

Tags: html, css

I wanted to put a navigation bar and its background image over an orange background.
[img-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACy0J.jpg)

But as I put `*{ background-color: orange; }`, it becomes like this [img-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXh0Q.jpg). The background image just disappears. I tried making **background-image: none;** & **position: relative** in navbar but still couldn't get the results  What should I do to over navigation bar and its back-image?
The css I have wtitten

```
.body {
   background-image: url(/Website/F1/mclaren-mcl35m-with-gulf-liver.jpg);
   background-position: center ;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   width: 100% ;
   border: 40px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .navbar {
   background-color: rgb(255, 123, 0);
   position: relative;
 }

 .navbar li {
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 14px 8px;
 }

 .navbar ul {
   overflow: auto;
 }

 .navbar li a {
   padding: 10px 5px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: whitesmoke;
   font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
   
 }

 .search {
   float: right;
   padding: 10px 15px;
 }

 .navbar img{
   padding: 2px 10px;
   width: 120px;
   height: 25px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .formula {
   padding: 150px 100px;
   font-size:30px;
   color: mintcream;
   font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*{ background-color: orange; }` means applying this color to all element. The asterisk (*) is known as the CSS universal selectors. It can be used to select any and all types of elements in an HTML page. So of course it will change background color for all elements.

Instead apply background-color property to particular element for which you want to change background color.